# function either returns None or says "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a program that will take two sets of random integers, and print a statement based on the results of those two sets of integers. However, when I call the method, I either receive "None" or an error stating "maximum recursion depth exceeded". I can't seem to figure out how to structure my return statements within these methods so that this works properly.

```
def genre(a,b):
    genreType = random.randint(a,b)

    if genreType == '1':
        genreType = "Fantasy"
        return genre()
    elif genreType == '2':
        genreType = "Sci-Fi"
        return genre()

def medium():
    mediumType = random.randint(1,2)

    if mediumType == '1':
        genre = genre(1,2)
        print("Play a " + genre + "game")
        return medium()
    elif mediumType == '2':
        genre = genre(1,2)
        print("Watch a " + genre + "anime")
        return medium()
```

Comment: Why a recursion though? Why even two functions?

Comment: you are generating int values using `mediumType = random.randint(1,2)` and comparing string values `if mediumType == '1'` so infinite loop is running without any return statement.

Comment: There are multiple issues with these lines of code. @VikasGautam already shared one. Plus, genre() method accepts two parameters while you are calling it internally without providing any parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if a function has a branch without a `return`, it will return `None`, e.g.:

```py
def something():
    if False:
        return "Thing"
    # There is no return in "else"

print(something()) # None
```

Second, comparing numbers to strings never succeeds:

```py
print(1 == 1) # True
print(1 == '1') # False
```

So the example you've provided can only always return `None`

---

Third, you are not returning anything meaningful from your functions:

```py
def genre(a,b):
    genreType = random.randint(a,b)

    if genreType == '1':
        genreType = "Fantasy"
        return genre() # call this function again, but with no parameters, why?!
```

If the condition had a chance of being true, you would be getting

```
TypeError: genre() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
```

I can only guess that you meant to do this:

```py
    if genreType == 1:
        genreType = "Fantasy"
        return genreType
```

Or, shorter and arguably more readable:

```py
def genre(a,b):
    genreType = random.randint(a,b)

    if genreType == 1:
        return "Fantasy"
    elif genreType == 2:
        return "Sci-Fi"
    # And you can add your own error to know what exactly went wrong
    else:
       raise Exception("Genre bounds must be between 1 and 2")
```

Comment: This was very helpful. The issue of comparing strings to integers, as well as returning genreType instead of genre() is what I needed. Thank you very much!